# How to loop Js and php script

Tags: javascript, php

so i have this script all.py wich returns an array wich i then print out on my page. Now i would like that to refresh the data every few seconds without reloading the whole page.

```
<?php $command = '/var/www/html/all.py';
exec($command, $out, $status); ?>
<html><body>
<p id="Duration"> Duration </p>
<p id="Artist"> Artist </p>
<p id="ElapsedTime"> ElapsedTime </p>
<p id="Title"> Title </p>
<p id="Volume"> Duratio </p>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("Duration").innerHTML = "<?php echo $out[0]; ?>";
document.getElementById("Artist").innerHTML = "<?php echo $out[1]; ?>";
document.getElementById("ElapsedTime").innerHTML = "<?php echo $out[2]; ?>";
document.getElementById("Title").innerHTML = "<?php echo $out[3]; ?>";
document.getElementById("Volume").innerHTML = "<?php echo $out[4]; ?>";

</script>
</bod></html>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What does the title have to do with anything? And have you done any research? I suspect this has many answers on google.

Comment: in brief: you will need an ajax call that returns some sort of structured format and you would then refresh those elements accordingly.  Are you committed to vanilla javascript only?

Comment: Yes i have done my research and i have tried multiple things. I wasted enough time so i decided i´d post it here. My question is how i refres that data without having to reload the page.

Comment: You should use Ajax for that, just like @NappingRabbit suggested.

Answer (score 2):

use **reload()** fn by setting time whatever you want.